How to map significant trends (p-value = 0.05) from raster file
I made a raster file (.tif) from a netcdf file, I want to analyze the data and make a map of some significant snow depth trends but it nothing seems to work.
I can make a plot of the data using the plot() function, but I can't calculate maximum values of variables in the file. I want to make spatial maps of maximum trends of the variables, but my codes aren't working.
df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(cropped_snow_stack), xy = TRUE)
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "SWE")

max_swe <- max(df$SWE, na.rm = TRUE)


breaks <- pretty(df$SWE, n = 7)


for (i in 1:dim(cropped_snow_stack)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(cropped_snow_stack)[2]) {
    y <- cropped_snow_stack[i, j, ]
    if (sum(!is.na(y)) > 1) {#Ensure no non-NA values
      lm_model <- lm(y ~ as.numeric(year))
      trend[i, j] <- coef(lm_model)[2]
      p_value[i, j] <- summary(lm_model)$coefficients[2, 4]
    }
  }
}


significant_trend <- trend
significant_trend[p_value > 0.05] <- NA

